# preg_match - pattern - last word within parentheses

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm trying to use a regex to get the last word within the parentheses if there is more than 1 word inside. In all cases will be `Baz`

```
! KEYWORD (\Foo \Bar \Ban \Baz) "/" "Hello"
! KEYWORD (\Foo \Bar \Baz) "/" "Hello"
! KEYWORD (\Foo \Baz) "/" "Hello"
```

Thanks

Comment: @Luzhin: question updated. Works, however, too many steps...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility would be

```
.*\W(\w+)\s*\)
```

Explanation

```
.*     #1 runs to the end of the string
\W     #2 backtracks to a non-"word character"
(\w+)  #3 captures all following "word characters" into group 1
\s*    #4 optional white space
\)     #5 mandatory literal closing paren
```

This regex works because it actively uses backtracking to find *"the last occurrence of something"* in a string (i.e. step #2 is repeated until the rest of the expression can match - or the entire expression fails).

In this case *something* is a sequence of word characters preceded by a non-word character and followed by a closing paren.

Comment: @stereofrog: You are right. However, I didn't know if closing parens may occur earlier in the string (though it's probably safe to assume there can't be). That's why I chose to use `.*`, and that makes the `\W` necessary.